# how to store a temporary attribute of an object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

In my application I have user model  by specifying some information my user object will get into updated_state. After one week  of that I want the date when my object get into that updated_state . And I want to use this value every week.(To increase their working time.) Without storing the value in database how to achieve this ?

```
state_machine :state, :initial => :not_initialized do
state :not_initialized, :initialized_personal_details, :initialized_office_details,
      :updated_state

event :finish_personal_details do
  transition :not_initialized => :initialized_personal_details
end

event :start_office_details do
  transition :initialized_personal_details => :initialized_office_details
end

event :finish_office_details do
  transition :initialized_office details => :updated_state
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use persistent data (i.e which are not used in the sessions ) without storing them somewhere. You have various option here:

- store them in the database. Seems the most reasonable option. You can either store them in the object, or create a different table/database
- store them in a different data store. Why not use redis for this, could be a good addition to a plain database, with some nice feature.
- store it in memory. Complex and not recommended especially if you want to be "crash proof"

Other options: files, messaging queue, .....

Without knowing exactly why this is needed, and why the database can not be used, that's the best I can tell

Comment: thank you for reply i will update my question for your convenience.

Comment: you did not explain why you don't want to store the value in the database (and if it's ok to use another data storage system). In all case, you need to store it somewhere. I've proposed different solutions, redis would be fine I think

Comment: I just want to run a whenever job every week after one week of the user get into the updated_state. And i have a column  state in my user model for this state transfer already. I just want to know the exact date of state change.

Comment: Now i start to use database or this problem . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using attr_accessor.